# Is there any way to mark an object to indicate it has been through a process?

Tags: java, immutability

Take, for example, immutability. How could I modify an object to indicate that it has been made immutable already and need not be wrapped again?

Let us assume we do not want to use reflection to scan for setters as that would be inefficient and insufficient.

Example:

```
// Deliberately chosing lowercase because it is a system attribute.
interface immutable {
  // Nothing in here I can think of.
}

// immute - have I invented a new word?
// What can I do with the return type to indicate immutability?
public static <T> List<T> immute(List<T> list) {
  // If it's not an immutable
  if (!(list instanceof immutable)) {
    // Make it so - how can I stamp it so?
    return Collections.<T>unmodifiableList(list);
  }
  // It is immutable already.
  return list;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something, but if an object is immutable and you can mark it immutable then was it really immutable in the first place?

Comment: @emory - perhaps not - I doubt we could guarantee the effectiveness of the label anyway until perhaps it becomes a language feature.

Comment: Is immutability an example and you are interested in processes in general (then I  recommend martin's answer).  If immutability is more than an example, then I recommend a functional language like Scala.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further playing with the idea produced this foul solution - it is horrible and almost any other trick would be better but I felt I should post. Please **please** find a better solution:

```
public class Test {
  // Deliberately chosing lowercase because it is a system attribute.
  interface immutable {
    // Nothing in here I can think of.
  }

  // immute - have I invented a new word?
  // What can I do with the return type to indicate immutability?
  public static <T> List<T> immute(List<T> list) {
    // If it's not an immutable
    if (!(list instanceof immutable)) {
      // Make it so - how can I stamp it so?
      return Hacker.hack(Collections.<T>unmodifiableList(list),
                         List.class,
                         immutable.class);
    }
    // It is immutable already - code DOES get here.
    return list;
  }

  public void test() {
    System.out.println("Hello");
    List<String> test = new ArrayList<>();
    test.add("Test");
    test("Test", test);
    List<String> immutableTest = immute(test);
    test("Immutable Test", immutableTest);
    List<String> immutableImmutableTest = immute(immutableTest);
    test("Immutable Immutable Test", immutableImmutableTest);
  }

  private void test(String name, Object o) {
    System.out.println(name + ":" + o.getClass().getSimpleName() + "=" + o);

  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    new Test().test();
  }
}

class Hacker {
  // Hack an object to seem to implement a new interface.
  // New interface should be instanceof testable.
  // Suggest the additional type is an empty interface.
  public static <T> T hack(final Object hack,
                           final Class<T> baseType,
                           final Class additionalType) {

    return (T) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
            Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader(),
            new Class[]{baseType, additionalType},
            new InvocationHandler() {
      @Override
      public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        // Always invoke the method in the hacked object.
        return method.invoke(hack, args);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: does `toString()` work? it seems that `proxy.toString()` is forwarded to `hack.toString()`

Comment: You will have to ensure that no other references exist to the original object being proxied - if you can do that then you can ensure the immutable conversion is performed and that this is done only once

Comment: @zhong.j.yu - No - it seems toString does not work - I have removed it as it is just a distraction.

Comment: @earcam - good point - but not my problem. All I want is to not re-wrap if I know it is unnecessary.

Comment: I truly hate having to mark this as the answer. There just seems not to be any reasonable alternative. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

If the check will be done on the same location, you could use a set or map, where you put all your wrapped objects, and check them later on in almost constant time. To avoid memory leaks, you could wrap them using [weak references](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/2006/05/04/understanding-weak-references) .

If the introduction of AOP is a (rather heavyweight) option, you could solve your problem using [inter type declarations](http://doanduyhai.wordpress.com/2011/12/12/advanced-aspectj-part-ii-inter-type-declaration/) via [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/). This way, you could just add a private member with the reference to the corresponding wrapped instance to the Collection interface, if I remember correctly something like this:

```
aspect Unmodifieable {
    private Collection java.util.Collection.unmofifieableWrapper = null;
    public Collection java.util.Collection.getUnmodifieable() {
        if (unmofifieableWrapper == null) {
            unmofifieableWrapper = somehowRetrieveUnmodifieableCollection(this);
        }
        return unmofifieableWrapper;
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the idea - but I would really like to mark the object in some way rather than just record it in a ledger of hacked objects.

Comment: Yet another reason to have a play with AspectJ - I have been looking for an excuse for ages. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with naming conventions in your classes.

```
interface MyObject;
class MyMutableObject implements MyObject;
class MyImmutableObject implements MyObject;
```

In my current project, I do something similar. I have an `interface` that needs to have a setter, but one of the implementing classes is immutable. When you call its setter it throws an `Exception` (it's setter should never be called, but it's there just to be safe).

The "information" you're looking for is more for the programmer than the compiler, so you don't need a language implemented "stamp".

Comment: Throwing an unsupported operation or having to implement a method that is never called is a bad code smell.  You should have two interfaces, the second interface has the setter and only the mutable class implements this (this second interface can extend the first).

Answer (score 0):

The Collections.unmodifiable* methods return subtypes of UnmodifiableCollection so you could check `UnmodifiableCollection.class.isAssignableFrom(list)` then test the concrete types.

Without using instrumentation, I think you're stuck checking types.

Comment: `UnmodifiableCollection` is not visible, so he would need to do this: `Class.forName("java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection").isInstance(list)`

Comment: @Lonenebula, +1 you're quite right, which makes the type checking smell even worse!

Comment: And there are many other immutable types that would need to be checked for - not the answer but worth being aware of.

Comment: You will either have to track (using some collection), tag (using instrumentation) or check (knowing all the types upfront).  Better to change your design so that you know it's been made immutable - easier said than done I know.